# Soundcloud API - (Sometimes) wrong playcount & ISRC code

Tags: api, soundcloud

I'm making a statistics system, and fetch some simple data from Soundcloud. But, when I use the very same link, but with different releases, sometimes it doesn't find anything at all, and sometimes the playcount is wrong. Further more, it always returns "null" for the ISRC code, even with tracks where I know it has indeed been submitted.

I use the following endpoint:
https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=$url&client_id=$client_id

Now, with the versy same endpoint, I get different results for:

https://soundcloud.com/krisoneil/kris-oneil-fisher-pouring-down-black-hole-out-feb-2nd <- works, and shows the correct playcount

soundcloud[dotcom]/krisoneil/heroic-pleasure <- works, but shows a wrong playcount

soundcloud[dot com]/blackholerecordings/luke-chable-kinetic <- doesn't work

Further more, the two that works both shows "null" for the ISRC code, even though I know they are entered.

I don't get how the same script sometimes work, sometimes kinda work, and sometimes doesn't work at all.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

All thebest wishes,
Kris

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this too.  You could try using the v2 endpoint which is unofficial and undocumented, but it does show the correct stats for me

For favorites - 
`https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/{USER_ID}/track_likes?&limit=200&client_id={CLIENT_ID}`

For tracks - `https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/{USER_ID}/tracks?&limit=200&client_id={CLIENT_ID}`

etc...

Comment: Ah, didn't know about v2 - awesome, thanks! Can I see the various endpoints somewhere?

Comment: @Kris Nope.  It's unofficial and undocumented.  Take a look at your network activity in dev tools on their site if you want more endpoints then the above.